# Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 1 bytes

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, ajax

I am receiving the following error:

```
Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 1 bytes 
Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed in
```

for the following lines:

```
   $person = unserialize($person);
    $allIds = implode(',', $person);
```

As part of the following function:

```
$person  = isset($_POST['person']) ? $_POST['person'] : '';
$allIds = '';
if($person!='')
{
    $person = unserialize($person);
    $allIds = implode(',', $person);
}

$person2  = isset($_POST['person2']) ? $_POST['person2'] : '';
$allIds2 = '';
if($person2!='')
{
    $person2 = unserialize($person2);
    $allIds2 = implode(',', $person2);        
}
```

In brief, I am trying to achieve this:
Its based on this example (they use one select instead multiple checkboxes form):
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp

Where the item being populated is based on the checkbox selected, where if the user select a duration of four and the sub category of the course to be in sql, than only those courses where duration is four and under sql sub category will be populated.

[image]

Below is the full main page (html and js):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            function showUser() {
                var selectedPerson = $('#testform').serialize();
                                                    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "<div class='loading-indication'><img src='ajax-loader.gif' /> &nbsp; Please wait... Loading New Courses...</div>";


                $.ajax({
                    url:'getuser.php',
                    type:'post',
                    data:selectedPerson,
                    success:function(res){
                        $('#txtHint').html(res);
                    }
                })
            }
        </script>

        <script>
            function showUser2() {
                var selectedPerson = $('#testform2').serialize();
                                                    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "<div class='loading-indication'><img src='ajax-loader.gif' /> &nbsp; Please wait... Loading New Courses...</div>";


                $.ajax({
                    url:'getuser.php',
                    type:'post',
                    data:selectedPerson,
                    success:function(res){
                        $('#txtHint').html(res);
                    }
                })
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <form id="testform">
            <input onchange="showUser();" name="person" type="checkbox" value="1">One<br>
                        <input onchange="showUser();" name="person" type="checkbox" value="2">Two<br>
                                                <input onchange="showUser();" name="person" type="checkbox" value="3">Three<br>



        </form>

        <br>
        <div id="txtHint"><b>Person info will be listed here...</b></div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Below is the php page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>

<?php
$person  = isset($_POST['person']) ? $_POST['person'] : '';
$allIds = '';
if($person!='')
{
    $person = unserialize($person);
    $allIds = implode(',', $person);
}




include("includes/db.php"); 



global $con;


$sql= "SELECT * FROM courses WHERE (course_duration IN ('" . $allIds . "')) LIMIT 10";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$sqlCount = "SELECT * FROM courses WHERE (course_duration IN ('" . $allIds . "'))";
$get_crs_count = mysqli_query($con, $sqlCount);
$count_rows = mysqli_num_rows($get_crs_count);
echo '<p style="margin-bottom: 8px;margin-top: 8px;font-size:18px;"><b>Number of courses available: </b>' . $count_rows ;
while($row_crs = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 

    $crs_id = $row_crs['course_id'];
        $crs_cat = $row_crs['course_cat'];

    $crs_provider = $row_crs['course_provider'];

    $crs_title = $row_crs['course_title'];
        $crs_price = $row_crs['course_price'];
          $crs_city= $row_crs['course_city'];
                      $crs_category= $row_crs['course_cat1'];

          $crs_date= $row_crs['course_date1'];


$crs_sdesc= $row_crs['course_sdesc'];
$crs_shortdesc = mb_strimwidth("$crs_sdesc",0,140,"...");
        $crs_image = $row_crs['course_image'];
        $provider_image = $row_crs['provider_image'];


  echo " <article class='search-result row'><center>
      <div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3' id='thumbnailContainer'>
        <a href='#' title='Lorem ipsum' class='thumbnail' id='resultThumbnail'><img src='$provider_image' /></a>
     <a href='searchPage.php?crs_price=$crs_price' style='color:black;'>  <button id='resultprice'><span id='resultpriceText'>$ $crs_price</span></button></a>
      </div>
      <div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2'>
        <ul class='meta-search' id='listDesign'>
        <a href='searchPage.php?crs_date=$crs_date' style='color:white;'>   <li><button id='resultInfo'><i class='fa fa-calendar fa-1x'><span id='iconText'>  $crs_date</span></i></button></li></a>
         <a href='searchPage.php?crs_category=$crs_category' style='color:white;'>   <li><button id='resultInfo2'><i class='fa fa fa-tags fa-1x'><span id='iconText'> $crs_category</span></i></button></li></a>
<a href='searchPage.php?crs_provider=$crs_provider' style='color:white;'><li><button id='resultInfo'><i class='fa fa-graduation-cap fa-1x'><span id='iconText'>  $crs_provider</span></i></button></li></a>
<a href='searchPage.php?city=$crs_city' style='color:white;'><li><button id='resultInfo'><i class='fa fa-map-marker fa-1x'><span id='iconText'> $crs_city</span></i></button></li></a>
        </ul>
      </div></center>
      <div class='col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-7 excerpet'>
        <h3 id='resultHeading'><a href='coursePage.php?crs_id=$crs_id' id='headingLinking'><b>$crs_title</b></a></h3>

        <div id='courseshortDescription'>
$crs_shortdesc
 <center><a href='coursePage.php?crs_id=$crs_id' style='color:white;'><button class='btn btn-danger' id='findoutBtn'>Find Out More</button></a> </center>
        </div>  

</div>

      <span class='clearfix borda'></span>
    </article>";
}

mysqli_close($con);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: php's `serialize` function has nothing to do with javascript form serialization - remove the unserialize call in your php

Comment: what would i replace it with, sorry i am bit novice and have mentioned in my post what I want to achieve. the results being populated are based on the checkboxes checked for instance if checkbox 1 and 2 check then the result wil be from 1 and 2 if only 1 than only one. i was having an issue a while back where it would only record the last checkbox

Comment: Dont replace it with anything. You will need to change the names of your input elements. To accommodate more than element with the same name, use the array syntax : `<input onchange="showUser();" name="person[]"` Note the square brackets

Comment: thanks for your answer, i made the change but is getting the following error now Warning: unserialize() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Comment: How could you possibly get that error if you removed the call to unserialize?

Comment: yeah i forgot to remove the unserialize call which I did but the problem persist, where it only works with one checkbox, where if i checked multiple checkboxes it only pulls the result based on the last one, where the others have to be unchecked. I would want that if checkbox 1 and 2 are checkbox their individual results are combined and populated. my question is nearly identical to this  http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp except I am using checkboxes instead

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73763/discussion-between-jonathan-etienne-and-steve).